# How to properly install the gmime library in linux (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, g++, installation, mime

I'm trying to make a simple email client and I have to parse mime messages which I then print in a QT interface. I read that gmime would do the job great, but g++ doesn't seem to be aware of the existence of the library.
So far I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install libgmime-2.6-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmime2.6-cil
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmime2.6-cil-dev
```

First thing I did really. It seemed to work well, but then

```
#include <gmime/gmime.h>
```

doesn't work (gmime.h not found).  I checked /usr/include and the headers are all there, but no other sign of the library in my file system.

Afterwards I followed these instructions http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gmime.html , but when I ran

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static &&
make
```

I got

```
test-pkcs7.c:36:23: fatal error: gpg-error.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I then tried a local inclusion of the library

```
#include "/home/user/Downloads/gmime-2.6.19/gmime/gmime.h"
```

But I got this error.

```
/home/user/Downloads/gmime-2.6.19/gmime/gmime.h:25: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone encountered this before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try compiling your program, try this:

```
g++ -o myprogram myprogram.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gmime-2.6`
```

The problem is that you need to tell the compiler which include paths to use (--cflags) and what library paths to use (--libs).

When compiling individual sources, you could do:

```
g++ -o file.o -c file.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gmime-2.6`
```

And then use `pkg-config --libs gmime-2.6` for the final step.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work and I will save the idea for a later use. Although, in the meantime I decided to use vmime instead. It is way more robust than gmime and it has a very thorough documentation.

Comment: More robust in what way? My answer above is in the GMime documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/gmime/stable/gmime-compiling.html. FWIW, I'm the GMime author.

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem so installed all that is possible in “libgmime” and

```
sudo apt-get install libgmime-2.6-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmime2.6-cil
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmime2.6-cil-dev
```

-

```
root:~$ ./configure
...
root:~$ gcc-shared res/res_http_post.c -o res/res_http_post.so -fPIC `pkg-config -cflags –libs gmime-2.6`
root:~$ cp res/res_http_post.so /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/
```